# In Jolt how to modified the keys of out put json and copy values from input

Tags: apache-nifi, jolt

In Nifi I want to copy all input values to output which has modified keys compared to input.

Input:

```
{
    "test": {
    "name":"John",
    "salary":"2500.145263" 
    }
}
```

Output:

```
{
    "company": {
    "fn":"JOHN",
    "sl":"2500.14" 
    }
}
```

Here I want to make the name uppercase and salary rounded off to two decimal places.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this](https://github.com/bazaarvoice/jolt/issues/726), there is not (yet) a pure rounding function in JOLT. However there is a `divideAndRound` function, try the following spec (it worked for me in the [online tester](http://jolt-demo.appspot.com) with your input):

```
[
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "test": {
        "salary": "=divideAndRound(2,@(1,salary),1)"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "test": {
        "salary": "=toString(@(1,salary))"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "test": {
        "name": "company.fn",
        "salary": "company.salary"
      }
    }
    }
]
```

The first part of the chain just divides the number by 1 and then rounds to 2 places, the second part of the chain spec is just to turn your `salary` field back into a string; when you use `divideAndRound` it will turn it into a numeric field. If you'd prefer the numeric field, you can leave out the second spec in the chain.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the ExecuteScript processor to do the conversions and write your own piece of code.

I have used ECMA script for this, but there are other options too.

```
    var StreamCallback = Java.type("org.apache.nifi.processor.io.StreamCallback");
    var IOUtils = Java.type("org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils");
    var StandardCharsets = Java.type("java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets");
    var flowFile = session.get();
    var obj = {};
    var strname = ""
    var strupper = ""
    var queryjson = {};
var sal 


if (flowFile != null) {
    // Create a new StreamCallback, passing in a function to define the interface method
    try {
        flowFile = session.write(flowFile,
            new StreamCallback(
                function (inputStream, outputStream) {
                    var text = IOUtils.toString(inputStream, StandardCharsets.UTF_8)

                    obj = JSON.parse(text)

                    obj.company = obj.test

                     strname = obj.test.name
                    strupper = strname.toUpperCase()
                    obj.company.fn = strupper

                    sal = parseFloat(obj.test.salary).toFixed(2)
                    obj.company.sl = sal

                    delete obj.test.name
                    delete obj.test.salary
                    delete obj.test



                    outputStream.write(JSON.stringify(obj).getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8))
                }
            )
        );

        session.transfer(flowFile, REL_SUCCESS)
    }
    catch (e) {
        flowFile = session.putAttribute(flowFile, 'error', e);
        session.transfer(flowFile, REL_FAILURE)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you!!, I know how to do in execute script but I want in Jolt Transform